# What is a good way of printing formatted 2-D arrays?

Tags: python

If I had an array that creates basic map tiles for a text based game that read: `tiles = [['.'] * 10 for _ in xrange(10)]`, how could I format the data in a way that is pleasant to view as a map for the player?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `join` function:

```
>>> tiles = [['.'] * 10 for _ in xrange(10)]
>>> print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in tiles))
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
```